# Indexing on MongoDB UUID field

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a table in MongoDB having UUID field named artwork_id, and i need to create index on that field, which type of index will be better?

db.artwork_images.createIndex(
{
artwork_id: "text"
}
)

OR

db.artwork_images.createIndex(
{
artwork_id: 1
}
)

[Image of UUID field here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvHsN.png

Answer (score 1):

Text indexes are meant to match words inside a field without having to access to the document. In this case you have an UUID field, so you are going to match the whole string every time.

> Regular indexes are useful for matching the entire value of a field. If you only want to match on a specific word in a field with a lot of text, then use a text index.

I recommend to have a look to this post [Performance best practices indexing](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-indexing)